# Strange file in /etc/systemd/system

Tags: linux

I just found file named "-ewww:w?:?" in /etc/systemd/system. When I am trying to run

`cat "./-ewww:w?:?"`

i get error "No such file or directory". What could it be and how to look inside this file?

Comment: What it could be is a failed attempt at vim. This looks a lot like an attempt at editing and then writing. I'm guessing its content is fairly similar to another file next to it.

Answer (score 0):

I created the exact same file. This is how I opened it

```
cat "\\-ewww:w?:?"
```